# Identify this accent - on topic or off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

Is asking about the accent or the like of a film/tv character on topic or off topic? For example, if I filled in the blanks, would the following question be suitable?

In *Happy Feet 2*, the elephant seal Bryan, known in Japanese as [Japanese name of character] speaks in an unusual voice [insert link to clip]. Is this a regional accent, and/or an accent associated with a certain profession? What would be the significance of such an accent?

As background, he is spoken by [voice actor], and in the English language version, his voice is very "blokey", has an Australian accent (possibly [strine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strine)) and uses Australian slang more typical of rural people than inner-city dwellers.

If not, are there other internet forums that would be more welcoming of such questions?

Comment: I think for all edge-cases we should work on a "allowed until otherwise determined by the community".